# How can I get notified when questions or answers I posted a comment to get more comments?

Tags: support, feature-request

I know I can click on the **activity** tab of my profile to see all the comments, questions, and answers I've posted. I also know that I can click on the **responses** tab to see all the comments on questions or answers that I've posted.

However, when I post a comment on someone else's question or answer, I can't seem to find a way to be informed. The only way I've been doing it is by returning to the question every once in a while.

Am I missing something? If not, and there is no way of being informed when someone else posts a comment on a question or answer I've posted on, I think it might be a useful addition. Something akin to subscribing to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the favorite functionality will probably help you. According to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work/53580#53580):

> Changes to the question will now notify users who have favorited the question. Notifications include comments to the question, edits, new answers, and edits to answers. This is a way to get updates on questions that you yourself didn't ask.

Comment: I marked this as answered because it answers the question. I would however, love to have a way to automate this function, so I don't have to manually favorite the question as a separate step from adding a comment

Comment: @Menachem that sounds like a feature request for the SE people... You can try posting it on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) (just try to figure out if it was asked before)

Comment: turns out it was asked a while ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have . Seems they decided to add the @ functionality instead.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can get notified is that if the commenter thinks their comment is worthy of your attention, they can [@mention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28042/be-notified-when-someone-leaves-a-comment-that-is-a-direct-response-to-my-comment/35915#35915) you in their comment. Of course, that depends on the choice of the commenter, so it's not all of what you're looking for.